# Modify TLD of URL of current tab in a browser action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a browser action that will insert some text between ".com" (or whatever TLD is there) and the "/foo.bar" parts of a URL.

For example, if I'm on "stackoverflow.com/questions" I want to be able to press a button in my browser and automatically be redirected to "stackoverflow.com.my.text/questions"

The button shows up in the right place (and looks pretty) but does nothing.

I modeled my code after [this example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/print/manifest.json?revision=119072). This is what I currently have:

manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "My Extension",
   "version": "1.0",

   "background": { "scripts": [ "insert.js" ] },
   "browser_action": { "default_icon": "my_icon.png" },
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]

}
```

and insert.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var url = tab.url; 
    var tld = /\.\w+\//;
    var url2 = tld.exec(url);

    var break = url.indexOf(url2);
    var break1 = break + url2[0].length - 1;

    var url1 = url.substring(0, break1);
    var url3 = url.substring(break1, url.length);

    var mytext = ".my.text";
    var urlNew = url1 + mytext + url3;

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: urlNew});
});
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I know basically nothing about JavaScript.

I did test the script itself by modifying the code at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2 so I know it matchs the right regular expression and spits out the right string.

I searched around for a while and couldn't find anything to guide me. Why does the example I posted work, but my code does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn anything, [forget about w3schools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done) and use reputable sources such as MDN.

That having said, after glancing at your code, I already see one blatant mistake:

```
var url = tab.url; 
var tld = /\.\w+\//;
var url2 = tld.exec(url);

var break = url.indexOf(url2);
```

The [regex's exec method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an array (or `null` if no match is found).
The [string's indexOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes a string. These arguments do not match, so the result you're getting will probably not match your expectations.

> I'm trying to make a browser action that will insert some text between ".com" (or whatever TLD is there) and the "/foo.bar" parts of a URL.

Then use the [string's replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var url = tab.url; 

    var urlNew = url.replace(/(\.\w+)(\/)/, '$1.my.text$2');

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: urlNew});
});
```

"$1" matches the captured group `\.\w+`,
"$2" matches the captured group `\/`.

<sub>Note: `\w+` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`, while a TLD can also contain a hyphen ("-") (see https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt). You might want to adjust your regular experssion if you want to match these URLs as well.</sub>