# Redirection with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm really new to the chrome app dev part. I want to know how can I make a chrome application that will read my current URL and redirect me to another.

For instance if I am on `www.stackoverflow.com` and user clicks on the extension icon then it will redirect him to `wwww.stackoverflow**NEW**.com`

Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify TLD of URL of current tab in a browser action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592989/modify-tld-of-url-of-current-tab-in-a-browser-action)

Comment: @Alex I have created a Chrome Extension to Modify HTTP request. It includes redirecting Urls as well. Checkout this: [Requestly](http://bit.ly/requestly-chrome-store) And all of the code is available on [Github](http://bit.ly/requestly-github-repo). You can use the same or you can try to use the source code and develop your own. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and you will be good.

1. Create a background script and define an entry for background script in `manifest.json`
2. In background script, define a handler on `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`.
3. Inside that handler, extract the url of current tab and check if it is the expected url, then just change the url of that tab.